# Customization on Task Board In Team Foundation Server not reflecting

Tags: tfs-2015

Hi so we are currently exploring Team Foundation server 2015 on-premise as part of our DevOps process.

Currently I'm trying out customization of the task board to add a "Pull Request" column/state in the board.

Steps ive done so far:

1. Exported the Task.xml file from the project "Wittest" in the Demoprojectcollection

witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://192.168.123.456:8080/tfs/DEMOPROJECTCOLLECTION /p:"Wittest" /n:Task /f:Task.xml

2. Modified xml to add the Code Review State

```html
<STATE value="Pull Request">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
              <EMPTY />
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </STATE>
```

3. Added transitions for the new state
4. Uploaded the updated file using with admin again

witadmin importwitd /collection:http://192.168.123.456:8080/tfs/DEMOPROJECTCOLLECTION /p:"Wittest" /f:Task.xml

5. Check the board but columns stayed the same 3 columns "To Do" "In Progress" "Done"
6. Exported the Task.xml again and saw the xml was updated but I am unsure why I does not reflect the changes in the board though.

Would really appreciate the nudge to the right direction for this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the state in the task work item type, you also need to modify the process configuration file.

Try to use [witadmin exportprocessconfig/importprocessconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration) command to import and export process configuration, and add the `pull request` state in the TaskBacklog:

```
<TaskBacklog category="Microsoft.TaskCategory" parent="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Tasks" singularName="Task" workItemCountLimit="1000">
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
    <Columns>
      <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.AssignedTo" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" />
    </Columns>
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="To Do" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Pull Request" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
    </States>
  </TaskBacklog>
```

I've tested on my side, it's working:

[image]

Comment: ooooh I didn't know there was another file to edit. Thank you soooo much!!!